# Spring Integration FTP in Docker container: not triggering flow

Tags: spring, docker, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-ftp

I am having quite a time figuring out where my issue is stemming from. I can run locally, I have built my `.jar` and ran that locally too.

I have my integration flow set as follows

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(final DataSource datasource) {
return IntegrationFlows.from(
    Ftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(template())
        .remoteDirectory("/folder/")
        .patternFilter("file_name.txt")
        .filter(
            new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(datasource), "")),
    spec -> spec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
    .transform(streamToBytes())
    .handle(handler())
    .get()
}

@Bean
FtpRemoteFileTemplate template() {
  return new FtpRemoteFileTemplate(ftpSessionFactory());
}

@Bean
public StreamTransformer streamToBytes() {
  return new StreamTransformer(); // transforms to byte[]
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore(final DataSource dataSource) {
  return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
  DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
  sf.setHost(host);
  sf.setPort(port);
  sf.setUsername(userName);
  sf.setPassword(password);
  return sf;
}
```

I have my datasource and my ftp information set in my application.yml

When I run this locally, I have no problems. When I run `gradle build` and run my `.jar` with several different openjdk versions (8u181, 8u191, 11.04), I have no issues.

When I run inside of a docker container using my `.jar` file, the problem arises.

My docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8u212-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY build/libs/app-1.0.jar .

RUN apk add --update ttf-dejavu && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app-1.0.jar"]
```

I turned `DEBUG` on and watched output.

Running locally and running the built `.jar`, I can see that the poller is working and it triggers the SQL queries to the metadataStore table that has been created in my remote db (postgresql).

Running in the docker container, I do not see the sql queries being run. which tells me that somewhere therein lies the issue.

With debug on my startup logs in the console are the same `INFO`s and `WARN`s regardless of running locally, running the built `.jar`, or running in the docker container.
There is this info message that might be of some assistance

```
Bean with key 'metadataStore' has been registered as an MBean but has no exposed attributes or operations
```

I checked to see if there might be a hidden `SessionFactory` connection issue by trying to connect to an invalid host, but I indeed get exceptions in my docker container for the invalid host. So I can confidently say that the FTP connection is valid and running with the correct host and port.

I am thinking it has to do with either the poller or my datasource.

Inside of this application, I am also running Spring Data Rest using JDBC and JPA, would there be any issue with the usage of the datasource bean across the different libraries?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `exec` into the container and try to ping the ftp server. It looks like it the ftp server address is not resolved from within the container.

Comment: @AvinashReddy I installed lftp inside of my docker container and successfully connected to my ftp server...

Comment: Also, seeing this ```INFO``` in the start-up logs ```Bean with key 'metadataStore' has been registered as an MBean but has no exposed attributes or operations```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the default client mode for the `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` is "ACTIVE", but in my case, inside of a docker container, the client mode must be set to "PASSIVE"

to do this, i needed to add one line of code to the `DefaultFtpSessionFactory`
you must set client mode to `2`  ... `sf.setClientMode(2);`
below is the final `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` bean.

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
  DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
  sf.setHost(host);
  sf.setPort(port);
  sf.setUsername(userName);
  sf.setPassword(password);
  sf.setClientMode(2);

  return sf;
}
```